# fatal error in stack

Tags: c, stack, codeblocks

I use codeblocks to compile my code in C language.but I faced fatal error.
my code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stack.h>
```

the fatal erroe is:

```
stack.h:No such a file or directory
```

What is my problem?

Comment: You've not told your compiler where to find `stack.h`.  Maybe you should have written `#include "stack.h"`, or maybe you should specify some command line options, such as `-I /where/to/find/include` when the header is `/where/to/find/include/stack.h`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `<stack>` is for C++ and not C. Note that it is `<stack>` and not `<stack.h>`. If you are trying to include a file named `stack.h` that you implemented yourself, try using quotes like this `"stack.h"` instead.

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <filename.h>
```

is for standard/system headers that come with the language/compiler/operating system, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

includes a well-defined header file that is part of the C standard library for IO routines.

The C standard does *not* define a `stack.h` header file, so the file you are trying to include must be from another source.

If there is a file called `stack.h` in your project, then you need to use

```
#include "stack.h"
```

Beyond these two cases, we can't help you - `stack.h` sounds very much specific to your project/setup. If you know what directory it is in, you can try adding that directory as an include path to your IDE.